# Evaluating convergence of a non-trivial series

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, summation

I am trying to evaluate whether the following limit is finite (as opposed to being $\infty$):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=2}^n  \frac{1}{n-1} \left \{\sum_{i=2}^l (i-1)\frac{(n-i)!}{(n-i-k+2)!} \frac{(n-k)!}{(n-2)!}\right \}^k$$

Note that $l$ is a fixed positive integer.

I thought about using the monotone convergence theorem for series, but this only works if the term in brackets^k for each fixed $k$ is non-decreasing as $n$ approaches infinity, but I'm not sure that that's the case above.

It may be helpful to note that the above can be re-written as

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=2}^n  \frac{1}{n-1} \left \{\sum_{i=2}^l (i-1) \frac{\binom{n-k}{i-2}}{\binom{n-2}{i-2}}\right \}^k$$

Would be very grateful if someone could suggest a way to evaluate whether this limit exists and is finite.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain your notation a bit? is l fixed?

Comment: Yes, $l$ is fixed..will add this to the question. Thanks for helping clarify

Comment: It doesn't converge for $l=2$ and the bit on the interior of the second sum is strictly positive so it won't converge for $l>2$.

Comment: Oh I see...the interior simplifies to 1. Too bad, I was hoping it would converge! Thanks for this insight.

Comment: Would it converge if there were an additional $\frac{1}{n-1}$ in the sum? Adding this to the question.